# Why is $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ in this proof of the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, proof-explanation

[image]

I stopped understanding the proof at "since $f$ is". I don't understand why $f$ is necessarily continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. After all, $f$ is some kind of abstract function, it can be anything.

Comment: What are the hypothesis of MVT?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Do you mean thesis to be proved by "hypothesis"?

Comment: it isn't necessary. We are interested in sufficient conditions, (minimal ) conditions that guarantee the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comment about how you stopped understanding the proof at "since $f$ is," the continuity of $g$ follows from the theorems (often called) algebraic continuity theorem (a.c.t.):

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval of some field (if your field if just $\mathbb{R}$ you will of course be fine). Assume your hypotheses ($f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ ). Since $fa,$ $fb,$ $a,$ and $b$ are all constants(scalars) with $a\neq b$, $\text{ }\text{ }\frac{fb-fa}{b-a}\text{ }\text{ }$ is a (defined) constant. Recall that the identity function is continuous. Then by a.c.t, the functions (of variable $x$) defined by $\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }x-a\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ and $\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\frac{fb-fa}{b-a}(x-a)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ are continuous on $[a,b]$. Hence, again because $fa$ is just a constant, the function defined by $\frac{fb-fa}{b-a}(x-a)+fa$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Therefore, by assumption of continuity of $f$ and the a.c.t, $g$ defined by $\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } fx-\frac{fb-fa}{b-a}(x-a)+fa\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ is continuous on $[a,b].\blacksquare$

The differentiability of $g$ follows similarly.

Comment: I fail to see how the ACT implies that f(x+a), where "a" is some constant, is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b). It mentions that under specific circumstances it will be the case for f(x)+g(x), but it doesn't mention f(x+c)

Comment: I did not say that $f(x+a)$ was continuous. (Even though it is. This follows from the fact that compositions of continuous functions are continuous.) I defined a new function — let’s call it $h$ — by the rule $hx=x-a$ (or $h(x)=x-a$ if you want to use unnecessary parentheses :p).

Comment: I just realized that I made a dumb mistake. I meant “Recall that the identity function is continuous,” not “Recall that constant functions are continuous.” Both statements are true, but the latter was not relevant. Mia culpa.

Answer (score 4):

No, it *cannot* be anything, since the statement of the Mean Value Theorem *assumes* that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I ran into problem here because I didn't read what the MVT states and assumes before checking its proof (and its proof didn't include MVT statements and assumptions explicitly enough).

Answer (score 1):

To apply Rolle's theorem of course $g(x)$ needs to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ therefore also $f(x)$ needs to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: So what? I don't see how "g(x) and f(x) need such properties in order for Rolle's theorem to work" proof that they both necessarily have them in context of proof.

Comment: @user161005 We are proving MVT for $f(x)$ by means of an additionl function $g(x)$ for which we apply Rolle's theorem, and the given hypotesis are necessary for RT to be true. Refer to [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem#Standard_version_of_the_theorem)

Comment: @user161005 Indeed $g(x)$ is obtained by the sum of $f(x)$ with a continuos (linear) function.

Comment: @user161005 Note also that the differentiability on $(a,b)$ is the minimum requirement, of course if $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ we can also apply the theorem.

Comment: You're right! Secant line function is a linear function and as such it's differentiable and continuous on [a,b]. A constant function is also differentiable and continuous on [a,b]. Combined with algebraic continuity theorem it makes sense that g(x) is differentiable and continuous.

Comment: @user161005 Yes exactly that the point!